# $ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+2}.....\dfrac{1}{n+n})$

Tags: limits

How do I find this limit $ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+2}.....\dfrac{1}{n+n})$

$(A)=\log_e1$

$(B)=\log_e2$

$(C)=\log_e3$

$(D)=\log_e4$

Please give me hint or something. What  i could see is $ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0 $ that is not even in the options.

Comment: While it's not the correct answer, $\ln 1 = 0$, so it was in the options.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196920/is-the-following-statement-is-true, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670508/solve-lim-n-to-infty-left-frac1n1-frac1n2-cdots-frac1nn, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73550/the-limit-of-truncated-sums-of-harmonic-series-lim-limits-k-to-infty-sum-n

Comment: Am i going to jail?

Answer (score 3):

$\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+2}.....\dfrac{1}{n+n}= \frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{1+1/n}+\frac{1}{1+2/n}+....+\frac{1}{1+n/n})  \to \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x} dx= \log_e 2$

Comment: Is there any method for finding the the bounds like you have take $0$ to $1$?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is invalid, since the number of terms in the limit increases without bound. Regarding a solution, recall that
$$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n} \approx \log_\mathrm{e} n+\gamma , \quad n \to +\infty,$$
where $\gamma$ denotes the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).